# ProxySQL is not cahcing query without a LIMIT clause

Tags: caching, proxysql

## UPDATE

### Not related to LIMIT clause: LARGE dataset is not being cached!

After hours of testing and observation, keeping the dataset smaller with LIMIT makes the cache to work, but a larger dataset is not being cached. Can you please direct me to some solution with this?

**Working** query: `SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' LIMIT 999`

**Failing** query: `SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' LIMIT 1999`

**mysql-query_cache_size_MB** = `20480`

==============================================

**ProxySQL** is caching the statement with the LIMIT clause just fine, but never caching the one without the LIMIT clause!

### Query

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' LIMIT 99;
```

#### Rule

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| rule_id | digest             | match_pattern                        | destination_hostgroup | cache_ttl |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| 31      | NULL               | ^SELECT .+ FROM lsk_options WHERE .+ | NULL                  | 9999999   |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

#### Status

```
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| count_star | sum_time | hostgroup | digest_text                                                                  |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1          | 113717   | 2         | SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = ?         |
| 1          | 0        | -1        | SELECT option_name, option_value FROM lsk_options WHERE autoload = ? LIMIT ? |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

##### Variable

```
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                         | Value |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| mysql-query_cache_size_MB             | 20480 |
| mysql-query_cache_stores_empty_result | true  |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
```